# How can I add quotes to my jQuery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm pushing new values dynamically in my array using jquery.

which then generates an array that looks like this `[1,2,3,4,5]` and i want it to look something like this `['1','2','3','4','5']`

so that it can be of use in my app.

EDIT

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.bookmark').live('click',function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var Id = element.attr("id");
    var I = element.attr("attr");
    var info = 'id=' + Id;
    var myArray = ('{{r.bookmarks}}');         #gets data from datastore..
    var myOtherArray = ''+Id;                  #current number i want to submit
    myArray.push(String( myOtherArray ));
    var arr = myArray;
    $('#array'+Id).val(arr);                   #newly formed array value added 
    var submitData = $('#array'+Id).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/addpage/{{user.email}}",  #page submit
            data: submitData,
            success: function(msg){

                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {


                    $('.i'+Id).text('remove');}
            }

        });
    return false});
});
```

the array formed is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and i want it to be like this ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'].

please help.

Comment: Javascript will automatically turn numbers into strings when necessary. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a very strange request, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: i'm using google app engine and i need to get specific data from a query (only data the user wants to see). how do i go about adding new variables dynamically to an array using javascript.

Answer (score 6):

```
var array_of_strings = array_of_numbers.map(String);
```

Or do it when you're pushing:

```
arr.push(String(yournumber));
```

OK, now that you've posted your code. Change:

```
$('#array'+Id).val(arr);
```

to:

```
$('#array'+Id).val(JSON.stringify(arr.map(String)));
```

You can't put an array into the value of a form element. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to JSON format, which is Javascript literal array notation.

Comment: ok my jquery array looks like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 without the brackets. in jquery i doesnt work. thanks anyway.

Comment: It works for me. `console.log(array_of_strings)` shows the quotes.

Comment: @kevinoutsideboxthinker for sure it works as expected so you are doing something wrong somewhere else

Comment: @kevinoutsideboxthinker You still haven't explained why you need to do this. Whenever JS or jQuery needs a string, if you give it a number it will convert it to a string.

Comment: @Barmar maybe just a concatenation issue. OP didn't provide enough info

Comment: it still is the same. i tried it on a div and not a form element and it still gives out 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 instead of ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'].

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is JSON. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Barmar you're a life saver man. i'll buy you a beer one day.

Answer (score 5):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].join(',').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a number as string use the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) function of Javascript.

Example:

```
var num = 15;
var n = num.toString();
```